# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package locks web.config after rebuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio-2015, odp.net

Adding Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package to a ASP.NET MVC project locks web.config after rebuild.

Steps to reproduce:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
- Create new MVC project (ASP.NET 4.5.2 Templates MVC, leave "Add Application Insights to project" checked, uncheck Hosted in Cloud and change authentication to Windows Authentication)
- Inside the project open web.config and leave it open
- Go to "Manage NuGet Packages..."
- **Install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package 12.1.2400**
- Rebuild your solution
- **Now try to make changes to the web.config and save it >>> brings up Save As dialog because your web.config is now locked by some process**

Not sure if all these steps are needed to reproduce this locking of web.config but this is how I can reproduce it. No other nuget package that I use reproduces this.

The only way I can circumvent this is by uninstalling the package. Is there another way to keep this package and not lock web.config?

**EDIT**

To unlock web.config I not only need to uninstall the package, but also remove all references to this package in web.config. If I don't remove the references in web.config it still gets locked despite uninstalling the package from package manager gui.

Comment: Yes, i have seen this happen couple of times. In both instances i either had to stop/start the application pool or the IIS server itself to resume editing.

Comment: IIS is not involved in the steps to reproduce. Happens regardless.

Comment: what helps you fix the locking issue? Does the web.config become read only?

Comment: You may want to restart your local IIS Express to remove the locking.

Comment: @cableload are you suggesting that Oracle.ManagedDataAccess has nothing to do with the locking? why?

Comment: i am not suggesting that, rather i am trying to see how to resolve the locking issue. As far as why the nuget package is locking it, i dont know and i know that it does not happen all the time, but sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

**Step 1:** Create a dummy project and add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package. Copy the package folder from \your_solution\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.2400 to a different location.

**Step 2:** In your real project uninstall the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package. Remove all references to this package/dll from web.config. Add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll from the copied folder in step 1.